# Errors when removing Spotify

Tags: uninstall, spotify

```
dpkg: error processing spotify-client (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 spotify-client
```

Comment: What command did you enter to get this message?

Answer (score 2):

Giving basic `apt-get` corruption commands.

```
apt-get -f install # Force installs to complete.
apt-get autoclean # Clean it all, retry -f install if it failed at first.
apt-get --purge remove spotify-client # Remove it.
```